# how to put regression results into a table in r

Tags: r, tibble

Im trying to take the output of the function `summary(dataset.regression)` and turn it into a table for a professional r markdown report to be shared via html. I have run a regression model on two variables in the dataset and would like to make a table of the p-value, std error and estimate and use kableExtra to make it look professional. However before getting to kablextra, is there an easier way to make this table than just entering the results manually in a table i.e extract the results I would like to make a table of from `summary(dataset.regression)`?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try [broom::tidy()](https://broom.tidymodels.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
# Load the necessary packages
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

# Extract the p-values, standard errors, and estimates
p.values <- summary(dataset.regression)$p.value
std.errors <- summary(dataset.regression)$std.error
estimates <- summary(dataset.regression)$estimate

# Combine the extracted elements into a single matrix or data frame
results <- cbind(p.values, std.errors, estimates)

# Create a table in R Markdown using the kable function
kable(results, caption = "Regression Results") %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = F)
```

Comment: Hi, that didnt work

Comment: Then pls provide more infos, like sample script and data etc.